# ASP.NET MVC Basics - Controller method does not return string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my first application in ASP.NET MVC, And I'm struggling with some basics things, somehow my Method does not returning string and I guess I did everything fine, here is my code:

Here is my Controller:

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public string Index(string name)
        {
           return "Hello from MVC" + name;
        }

    }
}
```

It's easy to notice there is no my "test" string which I thought I provided to a method :/

[image]

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is ok to answer on my own question, because noone else replied, and I've found what was an Issue here, the parameter that I'm passing into Controller's method should be the same name as a parameter that is listed in this method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

so "name" parameter didn't work in my case because in RegisterRoutes method there is written  `url: "{controller}/{action}/**{id}**`", it is possible to notice on the end it's written `{id}`, if I wanted to work it as in my case I should write there `{name}`